# CMS Hierarchy isn't displaying menu left magento 2.1.1

Tags: magento-2.1.1, cms-pages

I have created some CMS Hierarchy, in my configuration I set to display menu left. It work correctly for node children, however when I go to parent node(Main menu), the menu left disappear, also the item in the main menu apear as not selected.
I want to show the menu left when I go to root item of CMS Hierarchy

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use the functionality of what the hierarchy does if there is no page assigned to a node.

Create the top level node without a page assigned using the 'add Node ...' button called 'Press Releases' with a url of 'press-releases' with the two navigation settings set to 'Yes'.

Then put the page you want to display for Press Releases as the first child node under 'press-releases', with subsequent child nodes as siblings, using the two navigation settings again like:

- \
- - press-release
- - - press-release-home
- - - press-release-1
- - - press-release-2
- - - press-release-3

The press-release node will always be displayed & you should be left with the following urls:

- /press-release which has no page so will redirect to /press-release/press-release-home
- /press-release/press-release-home
- /press-release/press-release-1
- /press-release/press-release-2
- /press-release/press-release-3